# Woocommerce Xero function not working - "Error: "Using $this..."

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, woocommerce

I have the function below in the woocommerce xero plugin.

```
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', $this->name, $this );
    }
```

I need to change

`'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', $this->name, $this );`

to this

```
'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', $this->billing_company, $this );
```

when I tried to write a function for my functions.php I keep getting Error: "Using $this when not in object context" which I don't understand.

my function looks like this at the moment;

```
public function xero_contact_name_1( $this ) {


    return $this->billing_company;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', 'xero_contact_name_1' );
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't name a function parameter `$this`.

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

You're hooking into a filter which has two arguments, a name and an instance of a class. You need to accept both in your filter in order to override the name with the billing company.

```
// This is a function, not a method, so drop public.
function xero_contact_name_1( $name, $xero ) {

    // I don't know what the object is so I'm referring to it as xero.
    return $xero->billing_company;
}

// 10 = default priority, 2 is the number of accepted args. Without that we won't get $xero.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', 'xero_contact_name_1', 10, 2 );
```

Following your comments, I'd like to add a little more about `$xero`.

The filter is taking two arguments: the current name of the contact and a reference to the object. Your callback is then expected to return a string which in this case is going to be the billing company.

The object instance is passed into your callback using the pseudo-variable `$this`. You can't however name the parameter in your callback `$this`. You need to give it a name.

I'm not familiar with what the object actually is so I'm simply referring to it as `$xero`. The object instance is then available to your callback function as `$xero` instead of `$this`. The return statement is returning the `billing_company` property of whatever the object was.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I understand what you mean up until return $xero->billing_company; this is the original file if 
 it helps identify the object? https://pastebin.com/QBfpSp5f

Comment: would the object be the class its in?

Comment: @Jonnygogo I've updated my answer to try and provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try following and let me know, as this is not tested at all ---

```
public function xero_contact_name_1($name, $this ) {


    return $this->billing_company;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_xero_contact_name', 'xero_contact_name_1', 10, 3);
```

Comment: i do not understand this part ($name, $this ) {

Comment: first one is taking the name which was passed to the filter and 2nd one is object, as nathan replied with $xero, same, I just didn't wanted to change your variable name.